# Pass arguments captured from minibuffer to shell command in a function

Tags: shell-command, interactive

I'm struggling with passing arguments read from the minibuffer to a shell command in a elisp function.

I've written the following so far:

```lisp
(defun perlclean (review clean)
  "Script PERL blablabla"
  (interactive "Foriginal: \nFclean: ")
  (with-current-buffer
    (shell-command
      "perl -pe 's/\\q\{.*} ( \{ ( (?: [^}{]+ | (?1))*+ ) \} )/$2/gx' %s\\ \\>\\ %s" review clean)))
```

The idea is to pass the first file (called `review`) through this `perl` command to get the so-called clean file.
I want to specify the name of both files (that could not exist, that's why I used `F`).

The present version of this script asks me for both paths/names but ended with `Wrong type argument: stringp,255`.

I work on Linux-Ubuntu.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. You're using `with-current-buffer`, which expects its first argument to be either a buffer, or the name of a buffer. In your function, this will be the value returned by `shell-command`, which is neither a buffer or the name of a buffer.

You've also used the strings `return` and `clean` as the arguments for `OUTPUT-BUFFER` and `ERROR-BUFFER`. Neither of these variables are buffers or buffer names, so I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen here, but it's not surprising there's an error.

To answer your actual question, it's straightforward to collect arguments from the minibuffer and pass them to a shell command:

```lisp
(defun perlclean (review clean)
  "Script PERL blablabla"
  (interactive "Foriginal: \nFclean: ")
  (shell-command (format "echo Review: %s Clean: %s" review clean)))
```

Running this command, you'll see the output of the `echo` command in the minibuffer, and also in a new buffer called `* Shell Command Output*`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is confusing, but you’re passing a string to something that expects something else.

Specifically, the `shell-command` function takes these arguments:

```lisp
(shell-command COMMAND &optional OUTPUT-BUFFER ERROR-BUFFER)
```

It takes the command to run followed by two buffers to use for the output and any errors the command produces. You’re passing in strings instead of buffers.

I suspect that you wanted to interpolate those strings into the command, but `shell-command` doesn’t do that for you. I recommend using functions like `shell-quote-argument` or `combine-and-quote-arguments` to build the command. See [chapter 38.2 Shell Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Shell-Arguments.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual for more information.